# How can I match proxy_cache_key in nginx with the path in proxy_pass if multiple slashes are used?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache

I'm receiving request in the form http://host.example/foo/ or http://host.example/foo// The requests are send to a backend server with `proxy_pass http://backend;` and cached with the key `proxy_cache_key "$scheme://$host$uri$is_args$args"` The backend then decides what should be done with multiple slashes.

But if /foo// redirects to /foo/ the entry is saved with the same cache key as /foo/, which results in a redirect loop.

Now of course I have `merge_slashes on;` which I'd like to keep, because there are a couple of location matches, that would get complex without it.

Is there something like `$unmerged_uri` so `proxy_pass` and `proxy_cache_key` would match?

Comment: There is $request_uri variable

Comment: Is this the raw value from the request? What I've found so far it's `$request_uri` is the same as `$uri$is_args$args`. But the documentation isn't completely clear on that and I haven't followed the whole code paths behind these variables.

Comment: It's a raw request uri. See https://pastebin.com/zqg9AWzz

Comment: Looks solid. Thank you. Also confirmed via source, that $request_uri is the unparsed uri.